# Keras layer with int inputs cannot be built

Tags: python, class, keras

I have a complex keras model in which one of the layers is a custom pretrained layer which expects "int32" as inputs. This model is implemented as a class that inherits from Model and it is implemented like this:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.models.Model):

    def __init__(self, size, input_shape):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.layer = My_Layer()
        self.build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.layer(inputs)
```

But when it reaches the `self.build` method, it throws the next error:

```
ValueError: You cannot build your model by calling `build` if your layers do not support float type inputs. Instead, in order to instantiate and build your model, `call` your model on real tensor data (of the correct dtype).
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: i'm having same error, did you manage to find out the solution?

Comment: No, I had to refactor to the functional style.

Comment: I see, me too i've endup using functional. I also tested with wrapper this in a sequential model and provide an input layer and it worked.

Comment: any update? functional API doesn't work since it gives a different error

Comment: @RodrigoSernaPérez, could you please post your functional-style solution?

Comment: Can you show the code of the layer class?

Comment: Assuming you already know how to reshape/pre-process the data tf.cast() should work to fix the int32 and float errors inside MyLayer() which is where/why the error is presumably occurring.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown when building a model with model.build.

model.build function build a model based on given input shape.

The error is raised because when we trying to build a model, it first calls a model with x argument depending on input shape type in the following code

```
if (isinstance(input_shape, list) and
    all(d is None or isinstance(d, int) for d in input_shape)):
  input_shape = tuple(input_shape)
if isinstance(input_shape, list):
  x = [base_layer_utils.generate_placeholders_from_shape(shape)
        for shape in input_shape]
elif isinstance(input_shape, dict):
  x = {
      k: base_layer_utils.generate_placeholders_from_shape(shape)
      for k, shape in input_shape.items()
  }
else:
  x = base_layer_utils.generate_placeholders_from_shape(input_shape)
```

x is a TensorFlow placeholder here. So when trying to call a model with x as an input it will pop a TypeError and the result except for block will work and give an error.

I assume your input shape is 16x16. Instead of using `self.build([(16,16)])` this, call the model based on real tensor

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(16,))
self.call(inputs)
```

Comment: You can visit the link to see the where the error comes from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ba1d02cfc7730048a39e4ba2ad9d3e3863e7cb2f/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L448

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround

I've encountered the same problem when trying to export model with multiple Int-typed input tensor as `SavedModel`. I worked around by overriding the `build` method and manually specifying `self._build_input_shape`. So you solution would look like:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, size, input_shape):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.layer = My_Layer()
        self.build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.layer(inputs)

    def build(self, input_shapes):
        super(tf.keras.Model, self).build(input_shapes)
```

### What happened in the original code

The default `build` method of `tf.keras.Model` object will treat by default input tensors as float tensors, which ends up throwing the exception.
Such behavior of `tf.keras.Model` is defined [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.11.0/keras/engine/training.py#L455-L475), where inputs for your model are created by `base_layer_utils.generate_placeholders_from_shape`, which will specify `dtype` as `float`.

### What would happen with the workaround

As `tf.keras.Model.build` would finally invoke it's super class's build function `tf.keras.layer.Layer.build`, the workaround skips `tf.keras.Model.build` logic that causes the problem, but you may have to add complemental code after that in case you rely on other logics in defined in `tf.keras.Model.build`