# Tensorflow Saving Error (from Tensorflow Example)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the [Basic Text Classification example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification) from Tensorflow on my own dataset. Training and verification have gone well and I am to the point in the tutorial for [exporting the model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification#export_the_model). The model compiles and works on an array of strings.

After that, I'd like to save the model in h5 format for use in other projects. At this point, the tutorial refers you to [save and load keras models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) tutorial.

This second tutorial essentially says to do this:

```
model.save('path/saved_model.h5')
```

This fails with

> ValueError: Weights for model sequential_X have not yet been created. Weights are created when the Model is first called on inputs or `build()` is called with an `input_shape`.

So next I attempt to do this:

```
model.build((None, max_features))
model.save('path/saved_model.h5')
```

There are several errors with this:

> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype string for Tensor with dtype float32: <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(None, 45000) dtype=float32>

> TypeError: Input 'input' of 'StringLower' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of string.

> ValueError: You cannot build your model by calling `build` if your layers do not support float type inputs. Instead, in order to instantiate and build your model, `call` your model on real tensor data (of the correct dtype).

I think this essentially means the input I defined to pass into model.build defaults to float and needs to be string. I think I have two options:

1. Somehow define my input layer to be string, which I cannot see how to do. This feels like the correct thing to do.
2. Use model.call. However I am not sure how to 'call my model on real tensor data' because tensors can't be strings and that is the input to the network.

I've seen one other person with this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786328/keras-layer-with-int-inputs-cannot-be-built), with no solution other than to rebuild the model in functional style with mixed results. I am not sure of the point of rebuilding in the functional style since I don't fully understand the problem.

I'd prefer to have the TextVectorization layer built into the final model to simplify deployment. This is exactly the reason the docs give for doing this in the example in the first place. (The model **will** save without it.)

I am a novice with this so I might be making a simple mistake. **How can I get this model to save?**

Comment: Hi mate, I am facing the same problem. Did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: Yes. I ended up rebuilding in the functional style. Based on this experience, I won't build models any other way since I can't count on the save to work properly.